# Automatic Image Level Adjustment in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-preprocessing

I've transformed an image from RGB to cieLAB and then extracted a channel. How can I automatically adjust the tonal range of the a channel like in Adobe Photoshop?

```
A = imread('image.jpg');
CT = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(A,CT);
a = lab(:,:,2);
%????? --> how to automatically adjust the tonal range of a channel?
```

Auto Level Adjustment in Photoshop:

[image: Auto Level Adjustment in Photoshop]

Comment: By example: a=imadjust(a);

Comment: I tried with imadjust(a), but the histogram of image has changed and it is not similar to Photoshop histogram. LINK to histogram: https://ibb.co/sRYZgQy

Comment: Please, share PNG-image  before and after processing in Photoshop.

Comment: Image before(left) and after(right) auto level adjustment (LINK: https://ibb.co/BNrX8J0 ). I transformed left image from RGB to cieLAB and then did auto level adjustment on a channel. After that, i excluded b channel from the image so that only L and adjusted b channel remained. Right image is the result. How can that be implemented in Matlab? Thank u!!

Comment: https://ibb.co/J37xfCk  -> here is histogram of a channel after auto level adjustment

Comment: @AlexAlex have you figured out? thank your for your answer!